# how to show single data in datagrid in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a problem in this code. i want when i press save button then only current data which is saved by me show in table, but my problem is the whole data of table show in grid, how to get rid off this.

```
//php code
    <?php
            if(isset($_POST['save_button'])){

            $qrydatabind='SELECT first_name,middle_name,last_name,father_name,mother_name,
                              number_of_dependents,dob,gender,identification_mark,marital_status,spouse_name,mobile_number,
                              email_id,adhar_id,pan_number,passport_number,tin_number,dl_number FROM USER_MASTER';
          $results=  mysql_query($qrydatabind) or die(mysql_error());

              while( $row =  mysql_fetch_array( $results ) ) {
                echo
                "
    <table border='2' style= 'background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;' >
          <thead>
                    <tr>
                  <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
                    </thead>



    <tr>
                  <td>{$row['first_name']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['middle_name']}</td>

                </tr> </table>  ";
            }}
            ?>
```

Comment: Firstly, you need to stop using mysql_* and go for something like PDO or mysqli as mysql_ is now deprecated.

Comment: you can write query to fetch last saved record.

Comment: thanks a lot friends , it's work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `SELECT` with `id` ORDERBY DESC and then fetch the first row only